# Double a in last name

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, uppercase

Im wondering how to make Latex sort last names with double a in a last name at the top of the reference list. As of now, my reference "Aasly" is sorted at the bottom of the list.

```
@article{aasly2019forundersokelser,
    title = {Forundersøkelser og bruk av kortreist stein. En geologisk veileder},
    author = {Aasly, Kari Aslaksen and Margreth, Annina and Erichsen, Eyolf and Rise, Torun and Alnæs, Lisbeth-Ingrid},
    year={2019},
    journal={SINTEF akademisk forlag},
    URL = {https://sintef.brage.unit.no/sintef-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2641011/SFag\%2062_rettet\%20navn\%20(1).pdf?sequence=1}
}
```

Im using this reference style:

```
\usepackage[backend = biber,    
            style = authoryear-comp,    
            urldate = long,     
            maxcitenames = 3,    
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Something to add in the reference itself to force it on top?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us if you load a package such as `babel` or `polyglossia` and, if so, with which language options they're loaded.

Comment: From [Wikipedia on Å](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85#Alphabetization) (emphasis mine): "Correct alphabetization in Danish and Norwegian places Å as the last letter in the alphabet, the sequence being Æ, Ø, Å. This is **also true for the alternative spelling "Aa"**. Unless manually corrected, sorting algorithms of programs localised for Danish or Norwegian will place e.g., Aaron after Zorro. "

Comment: Please share a fully compilable example document with us that reproduces the undesirable sorting. Sorting may depend on your document's language settings. A self-contained example document makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing. If you need help coming up with an example document, have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: @Marijn I believe your above comment deserves to be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can realize from Marijn's and Mico's comments, if you're using `babel` with `danish`, Aasly will come after Zorro.

However, you can always change the order the references are printed by using `sortkey`.

Compare the result with `sortkey={Asly}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{aasly2019forundersokelser,
    title = {Forundersøkelser og bruk av kortreist stein. En geologisk veileder},
    author = {Aasly, Kari Aslaksen and Margreth, Annina and Erichsen, Eyolf and Rise, Torun and Alnæs, Lisbeth-Ingrid},
    sortkey={Asly},
    year={2019},
    journal={SINTEF akademisk forlag},
    URL = {https://sintef.brage.unit.no/sintef-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2641011/SFag\%2062_rettet\%20navn\%20(1).pdf?sequence=1}
    }
@article{zorro,
    title = {Something},
    author = {Zorro, Diego},
    year={2019},
    journal={De La Vega publishing}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend = biber,    
            style = authoryear-comp,    
            urldate = long,     
            maxcitenames = 3,    
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
 
\begin{document}
    A citation \textcite{aasly2019forundersokelser}
    another citation \textcite{zorro}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

with the default behavior without `sortkey`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{aasly2019forundersokelser,
    title = {Forundersøkelser og bruk av kortreist stein. En geologisk veileder},
    author = {Aasly, Kari Aslaksen and Margreth, Annina and Erichsen, Eyolf and Rise, Torun and Alnæs, Lisbeth-Ingrid},
    year={2019},
    journal={SINTEF akademisk forlag},
    URL = {https://sintef.brage.unit.no/sintef-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2641011/SFag\%2062_rettet\%20navn\%20(1).pdf?sequence=1}
    }
@article{zorro,
    title = {Something},
    author = {Zorro, Diego},
    year={2019},
    journal={De La Vega publishing}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend = biber,    
            style = authoryear-comp,    
            urldate = long,     
            maxcitenames = 3,    
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
 
\begin{document}
    A citation \textcite{aasly2019forundersokelser}
    another citation \textcite{zorro}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]